# PHP string comparison weirdness

Tags: php, string, drupal, comparison

I'm comparing a string from the database to a list of strings in an array:

```
if (in_array($entry, array('Söme&nbsp;string', 'other-string')))
```

This works for `other-string`, but not for `Söme&nbsp;string`, the main difference beeing that this string has an umlaut and an html entity in it. If `$entry` is `Söme&nbsp;string` in the database, the comparison fails, even though it should be the same string.

I also tried `strcmp` and direct comparison using `===` and `==`, but the comparison is always negative. I also tried `utf8_encode` before comparison, but that did nothing.

The database is using UTF-8, I fetch the data using Drupal API functions and my php file is also UTF-8 encoded. If I print `$entry` and `Söme&nbsp;string` to the output HTML, they are indistinguishable.

Any idea what could be causing this behaviour?

**Update**

Thanks for the help. It seems the `&nbsp;` is converted on the way and is stored as a real non-breaking space in the database, not as an HTML entity. Printing it converts it back to an HTML entity (or maybe Firebug does that when I look at it).

The output of var_dump() (using print function, taken from resulting html source):

`$entry:  string(14) "Söme&nbsp;string"`

`"Söme&nbsp;string": string(18) "Söme&nbsp;string"`

(I've edited the string as the real one contains a name)

**Update 2**

I've changed the string to `"Some&nbsp;string"` and here's the output of

```
var_dump(bin2hex($entry));
var_dump(bin2hex('Some&nbsp;string'));

$entry: string(24) "536f6d65c2a0737472696e67"
"Some&nbsp;string": string(32) "536f6d65266e6273703b737472696e67"
```

Comment: What encoding does the connection have?

Comment: what encoding does the PHP file have? (the one which defines the hard-coded string), or whatever source you use for comparison.

Comment: @Gumbo Drupal uses UTF-8 everywhere, so I'm pretty sure the connection is also using UTF-8

Comment: @Alexander The php file is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Is the form where you enter `$entry` UTF-8 encoded as well?

Comment: @Fabian: Better play it safe: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%'; SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';` (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then the strings are not the same. Perhaps:

- `$entry` has an actual space instead of a non-breaking space.
- One has the HTML entity `&nbsp;` while the other has an actual non-breaking space.
- In one of the scripts the character `ö` is decomposed and in the other it isn't.

Try to `var_dump` the array and `$entry`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `$entry` contained a UTF-8 encoded non-breaking space (0xc2a0). Just calling html_entities on it did not work, because I did not specify the charset. So my solution is the following:

```
htmlentities($entry, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
```